# How to upload apk file to sauce labs and get saucelabs url of temporary storage?

Tags: android, selenium, curl, automation, saucelabs

I am new to saucelabs.When I tried the following in cmd prompt to upload my apk file to saucelabs, I am getting the following Error.Can you pls help
in this?

C:\curl -u gkyrreport:e4fc33sfdsf45--41b2-9eeed6638 -X POST  –H “Content-Type:application/octet-stream” “https://saucelabs.com/rest/v1/storage/gkyrreport/mine.apk?overwrite=true” –data-binary @mine.apk

curl: (6) Could not resolve host: -H; Host not found

curl: (6) Could not resolve host: "Content-Type:application; Host not found

curl: (1) Protocol "https not supported or disabled in libcurl

curl: (6) Could not resolve host: -data-binary; Host not found

curl: (6) Could not resolve host: YourReport.apk; Host not found

Comment: Please stop vandalizing your questions. [They belong to the community, not to you.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/licensing)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you used an en-dash for the `-H` option and the `--data-binary` option. When you type your command, make sure that you use the minus key for options. If you copy and paste from somewhere you may have to edit your line to convert the en-dash characters to minuses. With the en-dash, curl interprets that argument as a host name rather than an option.

And note how it is `--data-binary` with two minus characters at the start.

(People commonly call `-` a "dash" but I've intentionally said "minus" above to avoid confusion with en- and em-dashes.)

Comment: I have voted to you.pls answer to my new question..to run java client for appium in saucelabs.

Answer (score 0):

Move the command to a single line and remove the backslashes "\". That fixed it for me.